# nuget content/contentfiles are duplicated in nested nuget package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

I have 3 projects which are nested in each other.

1. `HtAlarms.Common`

   - Has a configuration file `HtAlarms.config`
   - A nuget package is created from this: `HtAlarms.Common.nuget`
2. `HtOpc.Alarms`

   - Contains the `HtAlarms.Common.nuget` package
   - A nuget package is created from this: `HtOpc.Alarms.nuget`

     - **HtAlarms.config is wrongly included in the nuget-package!**
3. `HtServer.ServerTemplate`

   - Contains the `HtOpc.Alarms.nuget` package

     ### - **HtAlarms.config is wrongly included in the root directory!**

`HtAlarms.Common` has the following directory structure:

```
+-- Config
|   +-- NLog
|   |   +-- HtAlarms.config
```

[image]

[image]

`HtAlarms.Common.csproj`

```xml
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Config\NLog\HtAlarms.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

---

`HtOPC.Alarms` has the following directory structure:

```
+-- Config
|   +-- NLog
|   |   +-- HtAlarms.config
```

[image]

[image]

`HtOPC.Alarms.csproj`

```xml
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtAlarms.Common" Version="6.0.0-fix-htalarms-config.68" />
  </ItemGroup>
...
```

But the `nuget` package has already a duplicate!?

[image]

---

`HtServer.ServerTemplate` has the following directory structure:

```
+-- Config
|   +-- NLog
|   |   +-- HtAlarms.config
+-- HtAlarms.config
```

[image]

[image]

`HtAlarms.Common.nuget` installs `Config/NLog/HtAlarms.config` - **Right**

`HtOPC.Alarms.nuget` installs `HtAlarms.config` - **Wrong**

Also `CopyToOutputDirectory` is `false`. Should be `true`.

Someone can tell me what's wrong here? Thanks!!

Comment: Please try to change the `Build Action` of  `HtAlarms.config` to `None` and then package it again to try.

Comment: In which project?

Comment: `HtAlarms.config` of the first nuget package `HtAlarms.Common`. Please change it and then repackage it.

Comment: Then it is not in the `HtAlarms.Common.nuget` package anymore..

Comment: After that, change the `HtAlarms.Common.csproj` file, add `<pack>true</pack> `under the item `HtAlarms.config`.

Comment: Hey @PerryQian-MSFT, I am really grateful for your great commitment to my problem! To be honest, I haven't tested it. I don't use a `nuspec` file. I set `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` and `dotnet ` automatically generates the nuget package. I have about 80 different nuget packages and it is mandatory that everything runs automatically without any manual adjustments. My solution is now a separate project `HtAlarms.NLog` which only contains the `HtAlarms.config` file. You can now install the file on top of it if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution with us and if you have any other issues about nuget later, please feel free to let us know.

Answer (score 1):

> Someone can tell me what's wrong here? Thanks!!

As far as l know, In **Net Standard** projects([new sdk format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format) projects and when it is packed, it can only be installed by [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) format ), when you change the `Build Action` of the file to `Content` and then click **Pack**, nuget will put these files into ContentFiles folder in the nuget package folder(`HtAlarms.Commonxxxxx.nupkg`).

When you install this package to a new project, these files from `ContentFiles` folder will be copied into the new project automatically.

And it is related to the `Build Action` rather than `CopyToOutputDirectory`.

With your further info, you did not want this file appear in the second nuget package `HtOpc.Alarms`and l suggest you can try this:

**Solution**

**1)** change the `Build Action` of the `HtAlarms.config` file in the project `HtAlarms.Common` to `None` first and then enter the `HtAlarms.Common.csproj` file to add `<pack>true</pack>` under the item `HtAlarms.config`.

[image]

[image]

then click **pack** and repackage your project called `HtAlarms.Common.nuget`.

**2)** then enter the second project `HtOpc.Alarms`, first, uninstall the old nuget package `HtAlarms.Common.nuget`. Second, [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) before you install the new nuget package `HtAlarms.Common.nuget` into `HtOpc.Alarms` project. This is important in case you install the wrong nuget version. This step does not add `<pack>true</pack>` into `HtOpc.Alarms.csproj` and you can repackage this new project `HtOpc.Alarms.nuget` directly.

**3)** For the third project, you can try the same step like step two to install `HtOpc.Alarms.nuget` in `HtServer.ServerTemplate` project.

**Update 1**

After I test, l found when l install the nuget package into a new project, the  `Copy to Output Directory` of the new imported file `HtAlarms.config` is set to `Never` by default. And l think it is the pack button's effect and use the default designed `xxxx.nuspec` file to pack your project and when you use `xxx.nuspec` file,  it ignores the `Copy to Output Directory` of the file.

So when you pack the nuget package `HtAlarms.Common.nuget`, open it and then add `copyToOutput="true"` to the `HtAlarms.Common.nuspec` file(Use zip tool to open `HtAlarms.Common.1.0.0.0.nupkg`)

[image]

**1)** add this node into the file `HtAlarms.Common.nuspec`

```
copyToOutput="true"
```

[image]

Besides, save this operation, clean the nuget cache, and then reinstall the `HtAlarms.Common.nuget` into `HtOpc.Alarms` project again.

**Update 2**

Since you cannot modify your nuget package later, l think you  use [nuget.exe cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) to package your project with `xxxx.nuspec` file rather than use **Pack** Button.

First of all, you should download [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and then follow [this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#windows) to config it into environment variable and then you can call nuget in CMD.

**1)** when you pack your project, do not use the **Pack**, open CMD, first enter the path which HtAlarms.Common.csproj exists(like cd `xxxxxxxx\HtAlarms.Common`).

[image]

[image]

**2)** type nuget spec to generate the package description file `HtAlarms.Common.nuspec`. In this file, you can name the package id, version, author, description and so on as you want for packaging the package.

For an example,just like this:

**Remember** to add `contentfiles` nodes and `files` node into it:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>1</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>

 <contentFiles>
      <files include="Config\NLog\HtAlarms.config" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
<files>
<file src="Config\NLog\HtAlarms.config" target="ContentFiles\any\Config\NLog" />
<file src="Config\NLog\HtAlarms.config" target="Content\Config\NLog" />
</files>
</package>
```

**3)** Before typing `nuget pack HtAlarms.Common.csproj` in CMD to generate the new nuget package `HtAlarms.Common.nuget`, you should **rebuild your project**.

When you reinstall it in other project, please remember to clean nuget caches first.

**Then** you can also use this nuget pack format for `HtOpc.Alarms` project.

[image]

After that, you can install this nuget package into project directly.

Comment: This is nearly working but: If I don't set `CopyToOutputDirectory` to `true`, then it is not copied to the output directory. That means I have to manual set it to `true`. This would not be so bad if the local path would not be used for that (see here: https://i.imgur.com/BaJy4xR.png)! So if my collegue or the build server is building the project, the `HtAlarms.config` is not beeing copied to the output directory!

Comment: Thank you for your time! But I'm sorry that this is actually not a solution for me. "Open the nuget package afterwards and modify the package". Everything is built automatically, deployed on our private `proget` server and so I'm not able to modify files manual afterwards. I helped myself and created a new project `HtAlarms.Nlog` where I only stored the `HtAlarms.config` file.